# android - MediaPlayer does not play when public static

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have seen many other posts on this, but I can't get this to work. I am just trying to use a MediaPlayer to play a simple song. It is not a button problem from the UI, as I can verify the button methods startMusic, and stopMusic are getting called.

player.play(); and player.stop() do nothing.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        player.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sadsadsad);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void changeLabel(View view)
    {
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextView.setText("Label changed");
    }

    public void playMusic(View view)
    {
        player.start();
    }

    public void stopMusic(View view)
    {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Again, the play and stop buttons work, and breakpoints hit the .start() and .stop().

Comment: I'm confused. Your title says your `MediaPlayer` doesn't play but the body of your post says it does??? What methods don't work?

Comment: I just tried to clarify. I the playMusic, and stopMusic methods, are called with the buttons, but player.start() and player.stop() do nothing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why is `player ` `static`? if you remove the `static` modifier I think it should work

Comment: I read somewhere else on here that MediaPlayers need to be private static. I am new to Android.

Comment: Nope, remove the modifier and see what happens

Comment: no dice. It does play if I add `MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sadsadsad); player.play();` to playMusic though, so the music file at least works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work because I don't have much experience with `MediaPlayer` but too much for a comment. Anyway, try

```
MediaPlayer player;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sadsadsad);
}
```

**Edit**

Try moving

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sadsadsad);
```

out of `onCreate()` and into `playMusic()`

```
 public void playMusic(View view)
{
    player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sadsadsad);
    player.start();
}
```

I also think you should call `player.release()` in `stopMusic()`. It might not matter here but I believe it would be safe.

Comment: Hey that works, but for some reason it only works once. If I hit play the first time, it plays, then if I hit stop, it stops. If I do it again however, it does nothing. Any ideas? and THANK YOU for the help.

Comment: Do you get an exception, crash? Or just doesn't do anything the second time? I'm stepping away in a minute and it might be a few before I can get back but I will check if you have an answer when I do

Comment: No crash, it just seems to not do anything the second time. Thanks again

Comment: @Siriss I have edited my answer. I haven't had a chance to test it but try that and see if it works.

Comment: That did work. THanks for all the help. Both solutions solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment about stopping the player and it not playing again.
When the media player is stopped, you need to prepare() it again.
If you want to stop the media player and not have to prepare it again i would suggest

```
public void stopMusic(View view)
{
    if(player != null && player.isPlaying())
    {
        player.pause();
        player.seekTo(0);
    }
}
```

If you look at the state list [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) you should know what is going on.
Also you are using a static method (create(..)) from an instance (player) instead of from the class (MediaPlayer)

**Edit:**

As you asked. Using MediaPlayer.create(...) is the proper way and if you are using an IDE like eclipse it will warn you that since MediaPlayer.create is a static method it should be used from the class (MediaPlayer) not the created instance. I am unsure if it will cause a problem if done via instance, but I follow the philosophy that all warnings are errors thus I try to keep to standard coding conventions just in case.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain more on using create() from MediaPlayer instead of from my instance?

Comment: Did the pause/seekTo solution work for your stop/play problem?

Comment: it did. Both answers are correct, and since codeMagic answered first I am going to check him, and upvote yours. Thanks again.